# Import Data from .xls LongText to MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a problem importing .xls to SQL. The Excel file has columns with some cells containing more than 2000 text characters so when importing I changed `nvarchar` to 4000 for each column. The import worked but one column truncated cells to 255 characters. I checked and the columns are nvarchar (4000, null) but SELECT MAX(LEN(column)) = 255, which is weird. I tried to changing `nvarchar` to `varchar(4000)` but this is not accepted. The messages are:

```
[Source Information]
Table: `Sheet1$`
Column: q1
Column Type: VarChar
SSIS Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]

[Destination Information]
Table: [dbo].[Sheet1$]
Column: q1
Column Type: varchar
SSIS Type: string [DT_STR]
```

Curiously, one column has Source Type: LongText and Destination Type: nvarchar and by default shows max characters and on import everything works well for that particular column (more than 255 characters). For all the other columns `nvarchar` to `nvarchar` works but cuts off at 255 even if changed to 4000 or 3000 characters.

I tried to re-save the Excel file to .csv format but then SQL shows me Executing (Error):

```
Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 13" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

Task 1: The "output column "Column 13" (62)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Column 13" (62)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

Task 1: An error occurred while processing file

The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure
```

I can't ask the client to reimport the data and save it as .csv  format.

Is it possible to format the Excel version in a way acceptable to SQL, like Source Type: LongText and Destination Type: nvarchar? (I’ve no idea why `varchar` doesn't work for me)

I already used simple tasks for Excel like changed cells to text or copy-paste by one column to text format.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189897/EN-US)

You need to specify Scan Rows settings either in connection string or in registry setting.

Answer (score 0):

When the import tries to decide what the the column types are in the Excel file it only looks in the 8 first rows. If there are no texts longer than 255 characters then the column is marked as VarChar otherwise as LongText (or a numeric type if that is more suitable).

There are two workarounds:

1. Put a long text in the top 8 rows in the column you want to be LongText.
2. Change the registry setting for how many rows should be probed before column type is decided (TypeGuessRows).

> To change the value of TypeGuessRows, use these steps:
>
> On the Start menu, click Run.
>   In the Run dialog box, type Regedt32, and then click OK.
>
> Open the following key in the Registry editor: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
>   Note For 64-bit systems, the corresponding key is as follows: HKLM\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\microsoft\jet\4.0\engines\excel
>
> Double-click TypeGuessRows.
>   In the DWORD editor dialog box, click Decimal under Base.
>   Type a value between 0 and 16, inclusive, for Value data.
>   Click OK, and then exit the Registry Editor.

[Source: Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/help/281517/prb-transfer-of-data-from-jet-4.0ledb-source-fails-with-buffer-overflow-error)